# Can't get stylesheet to link properly with Django Framework (using localhost)

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to link it in the header of html file in the following path:

```
main/home/templates/home/index.html
```

And the style.css lives in

```
main/main/stylesheet/style.css
```

And this is my link in the index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main/stylesheet/style.css">
```

Is something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should go for:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main/stylesheet/style.css">
```

so you need a relative path.